# cant connect to node.js heroku app using dio library

Tags: node.js, http, flutter, heroku, dart

I am building a backend using node.js and express and I deployed it to heroku and it works okay.

I have tested it using postman and it works okay but when using dio library in the flutter app it fails and cant connect with error 404.

this only happens with dio library.

my app link:

```
https://APP-NAME.herokuapp.com
```

and when I try to reach it I use:

```
Response response = await Dio().post('/login');
```

but it fails.

help me,

Thanks,

Comment: What's the error on client-side and server-side?

Comment: that was heroku related, thanks regarding your help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was heroku related, Thanks